# Servlet+JSP (Netbeans): The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets, netbeans

Good day. I'm having a problem with my JSP Web System and I'm seeking help regarding my transmit function.

Basically, the transmit button is like a deactivate button, that once I clicked, it changes the transmit status (which is named dsTransmit in my SQLdb) from 'pending' to 'inactive'. I have copied the code I did for the delete with some alterations, which is working perfectly.

However, when I do it on the Transmit button, it doesn't forward the data to update. It, however, sends this error.

> type Status report, messageNot Found, descriptionThe requested resource is not available.

Note that I am using Glassfish Server and Netbeans.

Here are my codes

**DataAccess.java**

```js
        public void transmit(int id){
        try {
            String sql = "UPDATE DailySales SET transmit = 'approved' where dsId = ? ";
            PreparedStatement ps = DBUtils.getPreparedStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DataAccess.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

**Transmit.java**

```js
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package servlet;

import dao.DataAccess;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author Thang
 */
public class Transmit extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String idTemp = request.getParameter("id");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(idTemp);
        DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
        da.transmit(id);
        response.sendRedirect("/CRUD_News/AllPost");
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

**web.xml**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>EditPost</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlet.EditPost</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DeletePost</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlet.DeletePost</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Transmit</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlet.Transmit</servlet-class>
    </servlet>    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EditPost</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/edit</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DeletePost</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/delete</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Transmit</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/transmit</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>    
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

**AllPost.jsp(button I used for the transmit function)**

```js
                    <center><a href="transmit?id=${p.id}" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to transmit this?');">Transmit</a></center>
```

Can somebody pinpoint what I am missing here?

Comment: can you check first whether your req. reach on servlet or not ? if yes then again check whether you req. reach to transmit(id) ? can you check it first then will see what is issue.

Comment: what do you mean by check? i'm sorry i'm a beginner at this. i tried debugging but the build was successful. I don't know what's wrong, the other functions worked.

Comment: i mean just put 'syso' into the block so that you can get at least idea, that req. goes from where to where and where exactly exception throws.

Answer (score 0):

[It works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mGTy.jpg)
Could you show your project?

```js
<a href="transmit?id=${p.id}>  ==>  <a href=" transmit.do?id=${p.id}


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Transmit</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: never work, because it's not solution of above question.

Comment: on a side note, the page doesn't tell the requested resource error anymore after i restarted netbeans, it just kinda refreshes.

Comment: May I see the html location in your project?